# Passing trait implemented on FnMut into helper function without moving

Tags: rust

I'm trying to have a set of functions that can take a `CharPredicate` which is my own trait that is implemented over a `FnMut(char) -> bool`, `Range<char>`, `char`, etc.

The goal is to be able to call helpers like this:

```
scan_until(';');
scan_while('0'..='9');
scan_while(|c| { c.is_digit() });
```

For some of these helpers I want to call them multiple times and pass them between functions. However, the borrow checker is grumpy at me with this example:

```
#![feature(fn_traits)]

pub fn helper<P: CharPredicate>(mut predicate: P) -> bool {
    predicate.test('a')
}

pub fn scan_until<P: CharPredicate>(mut predicate: P) {
    // [A] This works
    while predicate.test('a') {}

    // [B] This doesn't: Use of moved value `predicate`
    //while helper(predicate) {}

    // [C] This doesn't either: the trait bound `P: std::ops::FnMut<(char,)>` is not satisfied
    //while helper(&mut predicate) {}
}

pub trait CharPredicate {
    fn test(&mut self, c: char) -> bool;
}

impl<F: FnMut(char) -> bool> CharPredicate for F {
    fn test(&mut self, c: char) -> bool {
        self.call_mut((c,))
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d32936d4c1fce9f2b230ee542d0e4933&version=nightly)

Case **A** works; I can call the predicate multiple times in the loop.

Case **B** fails because I'm moving the predicate into the helper in the first iteration. This makes sense to me.

Case **C** is my attempt at fixing `B` so that it works, I want to pass a reference to the closure in to allow it to be called.

Changing `helper` to take `&mut P` does allow Case **C** to work, but `helper` can also be called directly, which means callers will have to put `&mut` in front of every call they make. I tried doing `impl<P: CharPredicate> CharPredicate for &mut P` but that ended up with conflicting trait implementations with the `FnMut` version.

Is this something I can get working or do I have to cave and use `&mut` in my helper function?

Comment: Referring to your link — please review how to create a [MCVE], emphasis on **minimal**. Your code only needs one implementation of the trait and no nightly features. The code posted here is better, but still doesn't need any nightly features.

Comment: That's why I wrote the reduced example inline here. The playground link was to where I was narrowing that down. Apologies if that wasn't clear

Comment: And to clarify, `self.call_mut((c,))` -> `self(c)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a closure is a valid implementation of your trait, then make a closure:

```
pub fn scan_until<P: CharPredicate>(mut predicate: P) {
    while helper(|c| predicate.test(c)) {}
}
```

Comment: Fair enough. I was hoping to avoid having to wrap it up further when I've already got an instance of the trait, but that would work.